# Order of "extends" and "implements" in PHP class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, implementation

Why order of "extends" and "implements" is important? !!!

for example
The right order `first:"extends" second:"implements"`
The wrong order `first:"implements" second:"extends"`

***The right order***

```
// first:"extends" second:"implements"
// works fine
class Student extends Person 
    implements Student_Interface {
    // .... 
}
```

***The wrong order***

```
// first:"implements" second:"extends"
// Give us 
// Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EXTENDS, expecting '{' 
class Student implements Student_Interface
     extends Person {
    // .... 
}
```

Comment: Because the PHP core development team decided it was important!

Comment: Why is `str_replace` not `string_replace` ?

Comment: That is a standard you have to follow. It means to ask like Why <?php is needed for php programming?

Comment: Why is the order or arguments to array_search() needle/haystack instead of haystack/needle?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand from comments
That is related to ***Core PHP Language Syntax***